# 127.0.0.1 can't be reached with apache running

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost

I set apache server to run on 8080 and 4433 ports (I changed all the references on 80 port in configuration  files as well as all references on 443 port so apache can start). And in XAMPP application it says that apache server is normally running. MySQL server is running as well. There is a solid connection with internet so connection isn't a problem. But when I tried to access 127.0.0.1 this message appeared on display:

```
This site can’t be reached
127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: How is the Listen directive set in the config file?

Comment: It's set to 8080

Comment: Does "netstat -l" show anything listening on port 8080?

Comment: Also does "httpd -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS" show a virtual host for *:8080

Comment: You mention your "solid internet connection" .... this is why I ask from where you try to access your server? From a browser on the same Computer or from somewhere else? 127.0.0.1 is always only from the same machine!

Comment: Tom, where can I see that?

Comment: Razenstain, this site is opened in tab next to one where I'm trying to access 127.0.0.1 so it's the same browser and the same machine.

Comment: Which OS are you using? Also as @Razenstein asks, are you running the browser on the same computer that Apache is running on?

Comment: Yes, on the same computer.

Comment: And I'm using Windows 10

Comment: ok, in a command prompt: netstat -An | findstr LISTEN

Comment: Will bring up quite a list but in the second column from left do you have any line ending :8080

Comment: Yes, it is on TCP protocol and it's listening

Answer (score 0):

Apache won't re-read it's config file automatically after you change it so make sure you've restarted the service.

Also enter the url as `http://127.0.0.1:8080` so the browser knows to connect on port 8080 rather than 80.

Comment: Well, I've clicked on stop button and then to start button for apache service if that is what you mean.

Comment: It is, I guess that didn't help. In the browser are you entering http://127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: Well, it solved my problem. I can run phpmyadmin on 127.0.0.1:8080 and it works just fine. I'm just wondering why 127.0.0.1 on 80 port is not working.

Comment: because you changed the Listen statement from 80 to 8080, if you want both you need two listen lines one with 80 and one with 8080. If that made the page load I'll update if the answer if you'd be happy to accept it.